# Symfony4 how to run _locale prefix in URL for all controllers?

Tags: routes, locale, symfony4

I am trying to set an "internationalization" on my website. In order to handle this problem, I need to set "locales" as a prefix for all controllers URL ( e.g. : mywebsite.com/**en**/page ), then I found this help on the Symfony4 documentation :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html

I've modified thoses files as follows

> config/routes.yaml

```
controllers:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'
```

> config/services.yaml

```
parameters:
    app.locales: en|es|fr|ru|mg
    locale: 'en'
```

> config/packages/translation.yaml

```
framework:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    translator:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - '%locale%'
```

If I write my URL as follows : **mywebsite.com/en/page**, everything works, but If I omit to write the _locale in the URL, for example : **mywebsite.com/page**, it returns a 404 error.
I would like it to reach **mywebsite.com/en/page** as "en" is specified as default_locale in my file.

What did I miss ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this trick does the deal:

```
#config/services.yaml

parameters:
    app.locales: en|es|fr|ru|mg|
    locale: 'en'
```

Just needed to add a **|** at the end of the app.locales line, now I can reach the controllers without _locale prefix

Comment: On Symfony 4.3.1 (not sure about earlier versions) this still requires double slash, .e.g: mywebsite.com//page

Answer (score 0):

Working method for Symfony 4.3.1 (maybe earlier 4.x too, did not test) seems to be the following:

```
# config/routes.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: '' # don't prefix URLs for English, the default locale
        '*': '/{_locale}'
```

And the rest as in the question. Note: with this setup '/en/' is optional, i.e. it will work both ways -- with or without it.